# Intellij automatically export test results from java

Tags: android, appium

In intellij I run a large number of classes with many test. Is there a way to export the tests result automatically ? ( i don't want to export after finish by clicking the export icon)
I want that at the end of each class (AfterClass) to tell him (by Java code) to export the result to different file name.

Thanks !